# Get Class of Custom Scala Object

Tags: scala

I have created a class called square extends an abstract class called shape. When I call getClass on square I'm getting: class A$A101$A$A101$square rather than just square.

I want to call getClass(or a similar function) and receive a value that allows me to check if o: Object == square.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 99.9% of the time using `getClass` is a terrible idea. What is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @MrD basically I'm trying to write a method that can take any object but should disregard anything thats not a specified set of objects. I'm new to Scala so I'm guessing I'm getting back a pointer of some kind before $square? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should have the types you are trying to filter subclass some common trait or class and then ask for that common trait/class instead.

Comment: @MrD Thanks for that I'll try that approach and update the question with the I come to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClass` isn't something you'll need very often.  You can query the type of an object with better abstractions, like `isInstanceOf` or [pattern matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html).

Here's some REPL:

```
scala> abstract class Shape
defined class Shape

scala> class Square extends Shape
defined class Square

scala> class Circle extends Shape
defined class Circle

scala> def isSquare(s: Shape): Boolean = s.isInstanceOf[Square]
isSquare: (s: Shape)Boolean

scala> isSquare(new Circle)
res4: Boolean = false

scala> isSquare(new Square)
res5: Boolean = true
```

Here's an alternate way to write `isSquare`:

```
scala> def isSquare(s: Shape): Boolean = {
     |   s match {
     |     case sq: Square => true
     |     case _ => false
     |   }
     | }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, thats exactly what I needed.